# How to return nHibernate entity with nested entity having specific criteria

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, iqueryable

I have the following entities in my nHibernate model:

```
public class Customer : Entity {

    public Customer () {
        this.Notes = new List<Note>();
    }

    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    //....
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note : Entity {

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual NoteType NoteType { get; set; }
}

public class NoteType : Entity {

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShortCode { get; set; } //ie. "X", "Y", "Z"

}
```

In my controller I would like to return a list of customers that have a note in the past 24 hours of a specific type.  So the ShortCode has a specific value.  My controller looks like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller {

    private IRepository<Customer> _repositoryCustomer;
    private IRepository<Note> _repositoryNote;

    public MyController (IRepository<Customer> repositoryCustomer, IRepository<Note> repositoryNote)
    {
            _repositoryCustomer = repositoryCustomer;
            _repositoryNote = repositoryNote;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var notes = _repositoryNote.GetAll().Where(n => n.Timestamp > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) && n.NoteType.ShortCode == "X");
        var customers = _repositoryCustomer.GetAll(); 
        //change above to only return customers with note from past 24 hours that has a short code of "X"

        //Not sure this is close to correct...
        //var customers = _repositoryCustomer.GetAll().Join(notes, c => c.Id, note => note.Customer.Id, (customer, note) => customer).ToArray();
        //but throws exception "Specified method is not supported." Seems to be failing in nHibernate

        return View(customers);
    }   
}
```

What do I need to do to get the list of customers that contain a specific type of note in the past 24 hours?  My thought is to use linq or IQueryable methods, but I'm struggling with both.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the collection notes is populated for customers in the _repositoryCustomer.GetAll() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
session.Query<Customer>()
       .Where(c => c.Notes.Any(n => n.Timestamp > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) &&
                                    n.NoteType.ShortCode == "X"))
```

(Please replace `session.Query<Customer>()` with `_repositoryCustomer.GetAll()` in your case.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't using Any... perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I would usually go for a solution like this -

1. First add a `Get` method to your repository to directly translating expression to nhibernate

   ```
   //can also sort to filter out best result
   public static IList<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
   {
       using (ISession session = OpenEngineSession())
       {
           return session.Query<T>().Where(expression).ToList();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then call this like this -

   ```
   var customers = _repositoryCustomer.Get(x => x.Notes.Any(n => n.Timestamp > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) && n.NoteType.ShortCode == "X"));
   ```

But you should always avoid `GetAll` in general. Such as these -

```
var notes = _repositoryNote.GetAll().Where(n => n.Timestamp > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) && n.NoteType.ShortCode == "X");
var customers = _repositoryCustomer.GetAll();
```

The reasons are -

1. `GetAll().....` will fetch the entities from Database to Memory of the Web Server and then perform filtering there. That is a very very bad idea, unless you have very fast connection and you have infinite RAM.
2. Sending the filter expression directly to NHibernate gives you the flexibility to use the full potential of your database system and keeps the network transmission to minimal not to mention uses only the memory it needs to hold the results.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed response.  I will have to look into creating my own Get method.  I'm fairly new to nHibernate.  However, when I used nHibernate profiler to check the sql I can see that the Where/Any combination creates a Where Exists in the Sql and doesn't bring back all with the GetAll() method.  So I have to accept Hazzik's response.  Thanks!